# Tools for code Evaluation

Tags: unit-test, governorlimits, code

is there any tools to test the logic at what point will hit the saleforce governor limits (applicable only)?? Any sophisticated tools other PMD to evaluate your code against the salesforce best practices and governor limits??

Answer (score 5):

You can try out CheckMarx tool for source code analysis. I have used that and it is very useful.

For more information refer [checkmarx](https://www.checkmarx.com/)

It verifies:

1. Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)
2. Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)
3. SOQL Injection
4. Hardcoded Ids/Password
5. Assertions in Test Classes
6. Governor Limits (Too many SOQLs or Query in For Loop)
7. NullPointer Exceptions
8. Query Exceptions (List has no rows for assignment to SObject)
9. LDAP Injection
10. XPath Injection
11. Verbose Error Reporting
12. Resource Injection
    etc.

For best practices refer these links:

[Security Tips for Apex and Visualforce Development](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=review_and_certification.htm&language=en_US)

[Apex code best practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices)

Comment: updated more items in the list